# What is the "meta user" tab?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, profile-page, meta

I saw many changes of the user interface on the **meta site**. What is the *meta user* tab (*check the below image*) on my profile page?

> [image]

Am I getting a new account with reputation points as a Stack Overflow account ([link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1531064/cataclysm))?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The account linked in the question is for **Meta Stack Overflow**. This is a new per-site Meta associated with Stack Overflow.

This site is used to ask the questions related to suggestion, bugs, and doubts about Stack Overflow.

Before this Meta Stack Overflow was the Meta site for the entire Stack Exchange network. This has been migrated to Meta Stack Exchange (this site). Questions related to SO should be only there.

This is reason you feel changes on the Meta site.

Comment: no no no , I think my meta.stackoverflow.com account change to meta.stackexchange.com . All SO sites will give 1 rep for new account.

Comment: @Cataclysm no dear. This is new site you can see meta.stackexchange.com site also separately it is exist .

Comment: Oh ! I see [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/)

Comment: @Cataclysm right, this is newly launched site.

Comment: @Cataclysm - The reason you think this is not a new website is: MSO is a new site with old name while MSE is an old site with a new name (i.e. the old MSO renamed to MSE).

Comment: @hims056 If so , why my rep does not start with 1 ? I got this new MSO account with rep as my SO account.

Comment: @Cataclysm - Because MSO is now [per-site-meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/per-site-meta) which reflects main site's reputation.